# Nunjucks : How to bypass autoescape with custom extension?

Tags: node.js, nunjucks

I managed to make async custom extension in Nunjucks.js and I still have some unanswered questions. The following one is one of them.

How do you configure your extension to not be escaping its output. 
My code looks something like that.

```
var nunjucks = require('nunjucks');

module.exports = function CustomExtension() {
this.tags = ['docs'];

this.parse = function(parser, nodes, lexer) {


    // parse the args and move after the block end. passing true
    // as the second arg is required if there are no parentheses
    var args = parser.parseSignature(null, true);

    parser.nextToken();


    // parse the content until end block

    var body = parser.parseUntilBlocks('enddocs');

    parser.advanceAfterBlockEnd();

    return new nodes.CallExtensionAsync(this, 'run', args, [body]);
};

this.run = function(context, arguments, body, callback) {


    var id = body();

    somAsyncMagic(id, function(html) {

        callback(null, html);

    });


};
```

}

This piece of code is used in node by the way. If that may spark some idea to someone.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have access to all internal filters, so the answer is `cb(null, nunjucks.filters.safe(html));`.

```
var nunjucks = require('nunjucks');

var MyLoader = nunjucks.Loader.extend({
    async: true,
    getSource: function(name, callback) {
        var res = '...';
        callback(err, res);
    }
});

var env = new nunjucks.Environment(new MyLoader(), {autoescape: true}); // !

function CustomExtension(cb) {
    this.tags = ['docs'];

    this.parse = function(parser, nodes, lexer) {
        var tok = parser.nextToken();
        var args = parser.parseSignature(null, true);
        parser.nextToken();
        var body = parser.parseUntilBlocks('enddocs');
        parser.advanceAfterBlockEnd();
        return new nodes.CallExtensionAsync(this, 'run', args, [body], cb);
    };

    this.run = function(context, args, body, cb) {
        var res = env.filters.safe(args + ':' + body()); // prevent escape
        cb(null, res);
    };
}    
env.addExtension('CustomExtension', new CustomExtension());

env.renderString('{% docs "<TEST>" %}"OK"{% enddocs %}', console.log);
```

Comment: Hey @AikonMogwai, this is `escaping` the string not `unescaping` my problem is that globally extensions are being escaped. I had to globally turnoff escaping. As my extension is passing html.

Comment: The result of my code is `unescape`-string: `'<TEST>:"OK"'`. The `escape` string will be `'&lt;TEST&gt;:&quot;OK&quot;'`.

Comment: Ok sorry at first glance it looked like you were escaping the html. Let me give it a shot on my side and will promote as answer if so.

Comment: Ok! It worked! Sorry! Only one little thing though. `autoescape` should be false.